# Clojure: how to explicitly choose JVM in the environment with Leiningen/Lighttable

Tags: clojure, jvm, leiningen, lighttable

In my Windows 7 (64 bits) environment, I have quite a few JVM available:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\j2re1.4.2_12\bin\client\jvm.dll
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin\client\jvm.dll
D:\programs\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll
D:\programs\Java\jre7\bin\server\jvm.dll
```

Currently, with Lighttable/Leiningen (I don't know which makes the choice, and how), it uses

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\j2re1.4.2_12\bin\client\jvm.dll

But I really would like to try

> D:\programs\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll

It's even more puzzling that when I type

> java -version

I got the following:

```
D:\yushen>java -version
java version "1.7.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_45-b18)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.45-b08, mixed mode)
```

It seems that's what I want to have inside Lighttable/Leinengen.

Could you show me how to make the explicit choice/configuration?

I tried Google, but couldn't find some leads.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I found this link: http://leiningen-win-installer.djpowell.net/

After running the installer, it has the function to re-configure leiningen, using it, I was able to configure my old leiningen to use my desired JDK: D:\programs\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin\java.exe, then the JVM instance in leiningen/lighttable is the desired one now.

The moral of the story: leiningen needs to be reconfigured with newly installed JDK with the configuration functionality of leiningen-win-installer.

It might be possible to configure leiningen manually, but I hadn't found a way to do yet. 
I tried to manually configure through my project.clj with java-command option, it didn't work.

Answer (score 10):

I found a Leiningen profile in

`$HOME/.lein/profiles.clj`

For me on Windows, `$HOME` was `D:\Users\carl` . More generally, it's the directory Windows will (usually) dump you in if you start the shell using `CMD` .
This contained:

```
{:user
  {
  :java-cmd "F:\\JDK8\\bin\\java.exe"
  :plugins [

    ]
   }
}
```

...which I was able to change to good effect.

Answer (score 7):

Put the JDK's bin directory in your path first. It's the surest way.

More detail. Windows, you can use the `where` command to see what version of an executable. It's either `where java` or `where java.exe` You can also look at your path from the command prompt by typing `path`. If you're launching something from the command line, and it's not undertaking strange measures to find the JVM, it should come up with the first one in your path, which should agree with the results of running the where command.

If the where command is coming up with something you don't expect, either add the right directory to your path before the entry that's coming up or rearrange your path so it's coming up first.

To test this in leiningen, start a repl, and evaluate this.

```
(println (System/getProperty "java.version"))
```

e.g.

```
Yoyo-2:Desktop bill$ lein repl
(System/getPnREPL server started on port 61475 on host 127.0.0.1 - nrepl://127.0.0.1:61475
REPL-y 0.3.5, nREPL 0.2.6
Clojure 1.6.0
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 1.8.0_20-b26
    Docs: (doc function-name-here)
          (find-doc "part-of-name-here")
  Source: (source function-name-here)
 Javadoc: (javadoc java-object-or-class-here)
    Exit: Control+D or (exit) or (quit)
 Results: Stored in vars *1, *2, *3, an exception in *e

ruser=> (System/getProperty "java.version")
"1.8.0_20"
```

In my experience, Leiningen has always used the version of java it finds in the path. No experience with light table though.

Comment: Thanks for your hint. It might work for some other situation, but the desired JDK's bin had been already in my machine's PATH.

Answer (score 3):

For Leiningen, you can edit `lein.bat` to point exactly to your desired Java SDK version. I don't know if the same could apply to LightTable.

Or you can set a global `JAVA_HOME`. That is really Googleable (or DuckDuckGo-able).

Comment: Following your suggestion, I tried to look at lein.bat, it's quite contrieved. I feared that I might mess it up even more so, so gave up. Settnig JAVA_HOME and rebooting yield no desired effect either. Thanks for offering quick help!